# Velocity Java template failing with Javascript element

Tags: javascript, java, velocity

I am using velocity templating for generating HTML JS script code. The problem I have is, for below code snippet when I try assigning image source element I encounter error because velocity is treating this as Object indirection.  How to I make velocity not to do this?

```
var img_$MyClass.getID() = new Image();
img_$MyClass.getID().src = "abc.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [formal reference notation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#formal-reference-notation):

```
var img_$MyClass.getID() = new Image();
img_${MyClass.getID()}.src = "abc.com";
```